# Remove dupes/sort from a Array of Associative Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, unique, associative-array, duplicate-data

I have a array of associative arrays

```
aa[] = ('Tires'=>100, 'Oil'=>10, 'Spark Plugs'=>4 );
aa[] = ('Tires'=>454, 'Oil'=>43, 'Spark Plugs'=>3 );
aa[] = ('Tires'=>34,  'Oil'=>55, 'Spark Plugs'=>44 );
aa[] = ('Tires'=>454, 'Oil'=>43, 'Spark Plugs'=>45 );
aa[] = ('Tires'=>34,  'Oil'=>55, 'Spark Plugs'=>433 );
aa[] = ('Tires'=>23,  'Oil'=>33, 'Spark Plugs'=>44 );
```

Two Questions

1. How can I remove duplicates according tot he field 'Oil'
       is there a array_unique which I can provide a callback which acts as a custom comparator?
2. How can I sort by a custom field 'Spark Plugs'

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know of a function you can use to do this.  You will have to do a foreach over the values of the array and do the uniqueness checking manually.
2. Use the [usort()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function and provide a custom comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually going and doing the usual duplicate checking, I did this

```
$aa2 = array()

foeach($aa as $key => $value)  {
  $aa2[$value['Oil']] = $value;
}
$aa = $aa2;
```

Then sorting was done by the key...

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, I think [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is what you need.

And, like Brian says, usort for your second question.

Comment: the problem with array_filter is that he needs to know whether or not there are any other entries with that value from within the comparator.  I couldn't think of a way to do that that was any simpler or clearer than just iterating over it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with remove dupes this way, is how do you determine which values remain, since you're talking about partial uniqueness.

This solution below just keeps the first to appear in index-order.  It's not exactly elegant, but it works.

```
<?php

$aa = array();
$aa[] = array('Tires'=>100, 'Oil'=>10, 'Spark Plugs'=>4 );
$aa[] = array('Tires'=>454, 'Oil'=>43, 'Spark Plugs'=>3 );
$aa[] = array('Tires'=>34,  'Oil'=>55, 'Spark Plugs'=>44 );
$aa[] = array('Tires'=>454, 'Oil'=>43, 'Spark Plugs'=>45 );
$aa[] = array('Tires'=>34,  'Oil'=>55, 'Spark Plugs'=>433 );
$aa[] = array('Tires'=>23,  'Oil'=>33, 'Spark Plugs'=>44 );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( arrayUniqeBySubKey( $aa, 'Oil' ) );
echo '</pre>';

function arrayUniqeBySubKey( $array, $key )
{
  $indexAggregates = array();

  foreach ( $array as $idx => $subArray )
  {
    $indexAggregates[$subArray[$key]][] = $idx;
  }

  foreach ( $indexAggregates as $originalIndexes )
  {
    $numOriginals = count( $originalIndexes );
    if ( 1 == $numOriginals )
    {
      continue;
    }
    for ( $i = 1; $i < $numOriginals; $i++ )
    {
      unset( $array[$originalIndexes[$i]] );
    }
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use *array_filter* for filtering your data:

```
$bb = array_filter($aa, function($item) {
    static $tmp = array();

    if ($filter = !in_array($item['Oil'], $tmp)) {
        $tmp[] = $item['Oil'];
    }

    return $filter;
});
```

This uses a static variable inside the function to "remember" the Oil already returned. This works, because *$tmp* is used only during the execution of *array_filter*. If you wrap this into a function and call it multiple times for example, *$tmp* will always be an empty array for the first call of the function provided to *array_filter*.

The second task, the sorting, can be done using *usort* with a custom sorting function:

```
usort($bb, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['Spark Plugs'] > $b['Spark Plugs']
            ? 1
            : -1);
});
```