# Php csv upload problem

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP CSV upload files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461090/php-csv-upload-files)

i have a csv file ,te file has fields like uname,password,fistname,lname,email.
My requirement is when i upload a csv ,it should check for duplicate username and email also it should chekc whether the uname and password values exists in the database.
Basically it has to remove all the duplicates and upload 
How can i achieve it ?

RONIE

Answer (score 4):

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

CSV like so

```
"usename","password"     #Header

"robert 1", you_wish
"robert 1", you_wish
```

Output like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => robert 1
            [password] => you_wish
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => robert 2
            [password] => you_wish
        )

)
```

Reference:
http://gist.github.com/385876

Comment: got duplicate checking frm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139571/remove-dupes-sort-from-a-array-of-associative-arrays-in-php

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be to place UNIQUE constraints on the username and email fields in your database, and look for a violation of the constraint when you try to insert a new (username, password, firstname, lastname, email) tuple.  If you've desginated one of these fields as the primary key, that's already got a unique constraint on it.

Also, I hope that you're not actually storing passwords directly in a database...?

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to do this in a few steps.

1. Receive the file through the upload
   form (or whatever method)
2. Read the file in (you can probably
   just use the tmp location that it
   gets uploaded to, or give it a
   temporary name)
3. Parse each line and check against
   the database
4. Write all the valid lines into the
   permanent location

Comment: I got the array Array
(
    [0] => Array  ( [username] => uname1  [fname] => fname1 [lname] => lname1 [email] => email1@email.com)

    [1] => Array  ( [username] => uname2  [fname] => fname2 [lname] => lname2 [email] => email2@email.com)
    [2] => Array  ( [username] => uname1  [fname] => fname1 [lname] => lname1 [email] => email1@email.com)
    [3] => Array  ( [username] => uname3  [fname] => fname3 [lname] => lname3 [email] => email3@email.com)
    
)
removing the array 2 since uname and emails are the same as in array0 ??????

Comment: I got the array Array
(
    [0] => Array  ( [username] => uname1  [fname] => fname1 [lname] => lname1 [email] => email1@email.com)

    [1] => Array  ( [username] => uname2  [fname] => fname2 [lname] => lname2 [email] => email2@email.com)
    [2] => Array  ( [username] => uname1  [fname] => fname1 [lname] => lname1 [email] => email1@email.com)
    [3] => Array  ( [username] => uname3  [fname] => fname3 [lname] => lname3 [email] => email3@email.com)
    
)
removing the array 2 since uname and emails are the same as in array0 ??????